# How to deploy a dockerised app to ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I’m trying to deploy an dockerised app on Ubuntu and I have:

- created a `/var/www` directory
- made this directory 777
- set the ownership to my `deployer` user
- cloned my repo into `/var/www/my-repo`

When I run docker `compose up --build` I get file permission issue when copying the contents of my app directory to container. If I change the permissions in `/var/www/my-repo` to `777` I don’t get the error.

I don’t understand why. I've used my deployer user to clone the repo and it is part of the docker group, owns the /my-repo  directory which is inside a publicly accessible directory. My questions are:

- How can I fix this so I can run docker compose up -d without having to change the ownership of the repo?
- Is changing the /var/www to publicly accessible a good idea?

I’m open to different setup suggestions.

PS: I'm also looking into using kubernets but it may be the next step